# SwiftUI How to assign @Published to another @Published

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

I have a view(`MainView`) with another view(`FooGroupView`) inside. Each time I click the item in `FooGroupView` then pass the value changes to `MainView`.

Like below:

The white view is `MainView`, the red is `FooGroupView`. If click `foo1` then the text should `Current:foo1`, then if click `foo2` then `Current:foo2`.

[image]

My code is here:

**Test.Playground**

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct FooRowView: View {

    var foo: Foo

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Color(.red)
            Text(foo.name)
        }
    }
}

class Foo: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    var name: String
    var id: String

    init(name: String, id: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
    }
}

final class FooGroupViewModel: ObservableObject {

    var foos: [Foo] {
        didSet {
            self.selectedFoo = foos.first
        }
    }

    @Published var selectedFoo: Foo? {
        didSet {
            print("You selected: \(selectedFoo?.name)")
        }
    }

    init(foos: [Foo] = []) {
        self.foos = foos
        self.selectedFoo = foos.first
    }
}

struct FooGroupView: View {

    var viewModel: FooGroupViewModel

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 32, content: {

                // Error: error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT.
                //The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.

                /*ForEach(viewModel.foos) { foo in
                    Text(foo.name)
                }*/


                Text(viewModel.foos[0].name).onTapGesture {
                    viewModel.selectedFoo = viewModel.foos[0]
                }
                Text(viewModel.foos[1].name).onTapGesture {
                    viewModel.selectedFoo = viewModel.foos[1]
                }
            })
        }
    }
}

final class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @ObservedObject var fooGroupViewModel: FooGroupViewModel

    @Published var currentFoo: Foo?

    init() {
        fooGroupViewModel = FooGroupViewModel(foos: [Foo(name: "foo1", id: "1"), Foo(name: "foo2", id: "2")])
        currentFoo = self.fooGroupViewModel.selectedFoo

    }
}

struct MainView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel = MainViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            FooGroupView(viewModel: viewModel.fooGroupViewModel)
                .background(Color.red)
            Spacer()
            Text("Current:\(viewModel.currentFoo!.name)")
        }.frame(width: 200, height: 200)

    }
}


PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIHostingController(rootView: MainView())
```

In `MainViewModel` if `currentFoo` has changes, then the UI should be updated.

When click `foo1` or `foo2`, the `selectedFoo` in `FooGroupViewModel` was updated, then in `MainViewModel` should get the changes (as `@ObservedObject var fooGroupViewModel: FooGroupViewModel`)

My question is how to let `currentFoo` knows about the changes of `selectedFoo` in `fooGroupViewModel`? I was thought this line could observe the changes of the `selectedFoo` and if any update then trigger the `currentFoo` changes and update the UI.

```
currentFoo = self.fooGroupViewModel.selectedFoo
```

But actually it doesn't work.

Any help? thanks!

I also have another question, its the comment in above code(Line 56 if paste my code into Playground)

```
ForEach(viewModel.foos) { foo in
                    Text(foo.name)
                }
```

this code make the playground error:

```
// Error: error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT.
                //The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.
```

without any other information in console. Not sure why. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just doing `currentFoo = self.fooGroupViewModel.selectedFoo` definitely wouldn't work - it just assigns to `currentFoo` whatever `selectedFoo` is at the time.

With your setup, you would need to subscribe to changes in `fooGroupViewModel.selectedFoo`, which could be done via a `Published` publisher, available because it's a `@Published` property.

Also, bear in mind that `@ObservedObject` only makes sense inside a View, so I removed it.

```
import Combine

// ...
 
final class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {

    var fooGroupViewModel: FooGroupViewModel
    @Published var currentFoo: Foo?

    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    init() {
        fooGroupViewModel = FooGroupViewModel(foos: 
                     [Foo(name: "foo1", id: "1"), Foo(name: "foo2", id: "2")])
        
        fooGroupViewModel.$selectedFoo
           .assign(to: \.currentFoo, on: self)
           .store(in: &cancellables)

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, just changed `cancellables` to `&cancellables` works perfect!